# Does changing the order of questions reflected in past quiz results too?

Tags: 7, quiz

I have two quick questions about implementing the quiz module:]

1. I have the questions in a particular order and about 100 people have taken the quiz.  We have implemented the quiz results download module.  If I CHANGE THE ORDER of the questions (make question #3 the new question #1) will the results (old one in particular) automatically UPDATE or will we have ‘MIXED’ data – some with the old question numbers and some with the new ones?
2. As you know, there is an option to present responses (answer choices) in random order.  We had NOT checked that box.  If we now check that box, will the old data get automatically updated?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has to do with the inner workings of the quiz module and it has already been answered in the module's issue queue by the maintainer https://www.drupal.org/node/2862591.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a copy/past from the answer to [issue # 2862591](https://www.drupal.org/node/2862591)

> It depends on your revisioning configuration.
>
> Out of the box, Quiz will version changes so that your old results are not affected.
>
> If you were to change the Quiz/Questions in any way, you may see issues with reporting since the quiz and question version IDs have changed, so new users will be taking a different version of the Quiz. But, this means that all data is preserved.
>
> If you turned revisioning off, reordering the questions or selecting "random order" should not affect old results or reporting as the question IDs remain the same. But you have to be more careful since changing something like removing an answer or question will definitely affect old results.
>
> I'd suggest trying on a test copy of your DB just to make sure.

I'm posting this as a wiki answer, hoping for it to marked as accepted, so that this question is no longer considered as unanswered also.